# Using Javascript to Validate Inputs on Gridview specific row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to create a "check input" script,

Basically in a gridview I have an id bound field, 2 dropdown's, 1 textbox and a checkbox that when It's clicked I want it to check the dropdowns are not the default value and the textbox contains a valid time, if so let the check remain if not untick the checkbox.

This is what I currently have but with no success.

```
function CheckSelectedRow(lnk) {

        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;

        var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;

        var ddl1 = row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

        var ddl2 = row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value

        var time1 = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value

        var regex = /^(2[0-3])|[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/;
        var test = regex.test([time1]);
        if (ddl1 != "Select Resource" && ddl2 != "Select Resource" && test == true) {

            return true;

        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
                           <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grd_issue_am" Width="95%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="false"
                          EmptyDataText="No Runs to Display" CssClass="mGrid" OnRowDataBound="grd_details_am_format" OnDataBound="grd_issue_am_format" DataSourceID="sql_grd_issue_am">
                          <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Run No">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="farm_name" HeaderText="Farm" ItemStyle-Width="300" HeaderStyle-Width="300" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="arrival" HeaderText="Arrival" ItemStyle-Width="75" HeaderStyle-Width="75" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="milk_type" HeaderText="Milk" ItemStyle-Width="100" HeaderStyle-Width="100" />
                                    </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                    </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Driver Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_grd_am_driver" OnDataBound="ddl_add_select" DataTextField="drivername" DataValueField="driver_id" DataSourceID="sql_driver_list" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vehicle Reg">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_grd_am_vehicle" OnDataBound="ddl_add_select" DataTextField="unit_reg" DataValueField="unit_id" DataSourceID="sql_Vehicle_list" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Clock In Time">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_grd_am_clock_in" onblur="this.value=four_digit_clock(this.value);"  OnKeyPress="return NumberOnly()" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Send Run">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_grd_am_send_run" onclick="this.checked=CheckSelectedRow(this)"  Checked="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Run Status">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl_grd_am_run_status"></asp:Label>
                                   <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="transam" Value="" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                          </Columns>
                       </asp:GridView>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you bind properly your data to the GridView it will put a DatePicker instad of a textbox. You should also put an example of the outputted html from your aspx page

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, javascript above is the issue I have, not choosing a datepicker over a textbox, and the outputted html has no relevance (although I will add the markup) thanks for the comment but potential solutions to the problem stated only please.

Answer (score 0):

you could use pure HTML5

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="opt-first">
            <option disabled>Select one of the below</option>
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            </select>
       </td>
       <td>
           <input type="text" pattern="/^(2[0-3])|[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/"
                id="txt-data" placeholder="Insert a data"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

however the javascript solution could be

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_grd_am_vehicle" bla bla OnClientClick="validate(this)" ></asp:DropDownList>
...
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_grd_am_clock_in" bla onblur="validate(this)"></asp:TextBox>

function validate(elem){
    var type = elem.type;
    var isOk = false;
    switch(type){
        case 'select' :
            isOk = elem.value !== 'Select one of the below';
        break;
        case 'text' :
            isOk = /^(2[0-3])|[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/.test(elem.value);
        break;
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

Comment: Pure isn't an option unfortunately, the problem with the JS it only validates its own control individually where as the requirement is to check all three controls and return true / false based on if all have passed their tests or not.